# ¿Como puedo hacer una acción sin activar un boton o tapGesture?

Tags: ios, swift

Como puedo llamar lanzar esta alerta sin tener que usar un boton o tapGesture. Cuando llamo el metodo desde el Body obtengo este errror : Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

```
 func alertView()
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "tenemos un error", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Acepter", style: .destructive) { _ in
        //
    }
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        //
    })
}
```

Comment: Estoy usando SwiftUI

Comment: Desde cuál método llamas a la función que te da error?